# How to do AOT compilation properly in Angular

Tags: angular, jit, angular2-aot

I am a bit confused by reading the [doc about *AOT*](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler). And I quote:

*You can compile the app in the browser, at runtime, as the application loads, using the just-in-time (JIT) compiler. This is the standard development approach shown throughout the documentation. It's great but it has shortcomings.*

I have 2 confusions here:

1. So this is decribing `ng serve` as far as I understand it, right?
   But in production, if I don't run my app this way, just `ng build`
   it and host it by a web server like apache, is this "ng build" *JIT*
   or *AOT*?
2. And this page describe AOT is quite complex to set it up, but isn't
   `Angular-cli` has taken care of everything to allow you to build
   your app just by: `ng build --aot` or `ng server --aot`, am I
   correct? So the doc should be for only when you want to do *AOT*
   manually without `Anuglar-cli`, right?

Comment: I believe that AOT document was written a while ago, before the Angular CLI was really ready. Angular itself and the CLI has progressed a lot in the last 10 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Angular CLI actually uses AOT for production build (`ng build --prod`) by default. You can see this if you ever try to bind a private value in your component's class to your HTML/view and build it (it wont work).

Comment: Are you saying this is an error which is detected at build time, not run-time so this is AOT?

Comment: Yes, haha, that is exactly what I'm saying. I mean if you've made mistakes in your development of a component, you've seen the screen probably go black even before you've navigated to that component. That's AOT in work. (Yes, AOT runs in development as well)